# Bootstrap list group striped conflict with hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to simulate [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) `.table-hover` and `table-striped` on `list-group`. First I have tried the following for hover:

```
<!-- HTML --!>
<ul class="list-group list-group-hover">
  <li class="list-group-item">...
...
// CSS
ul.list-group.list-group-hover li:hover{
    background: $table-bg-hover;
}
```

The above code works fine and it generates hover over each list's item.

However, trying to add `striped` like table as the following code, does not work, i.e the strip effect only works but the hover is not working.

```
<!-- HTML -->

<ul class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped">
...

// CSS
ul.list-group.list-group-hover li:hover{
    background: $table-bg-hover;
}
ul.list-group.list-group-striped li:nth-of-type(odd){
    background: $table-bg-accent;
}
ul.list-group.list-group-striped li:nth-of-type(even){
    background: $body-bg;
}
```

I don't know how could I make the two effects, hover and stripped, working at the same time as table do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:hover` needs to come last

```css
ul.list-group.list-group-striped li:nth-of-type(odd){
    background: blue;
}
ul.list-group.list-group-striped li:nth-of-type(even){
    background: purple;
}
ul.list-group.list-group-hover li:hover{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped">
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>asdf</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, using the standard bootstrap 5 colours. Based on the [official example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/list-groups).

You could tweak the stripe and hover colours.

```css
.list-group.list-group-striped .list-group-item:not(.active):nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: var(--bs-list-group-action-hover-bg);
}
.list-group.list-group-striped .list-group-item:not(.active):hover {
  background-color: var(--bs-list-group-action-active-bg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="list-group list-group-striped w-auto">

    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3">
        <img src="https://github.com/twbs.png" alt="twbs" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" width="32" height="32">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <h6 class="mb-0">List group item heading</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</p>
            </div>
            <small class="opacity-50 text-nowrap">now</small>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3">
        <img src="https://github.com/twbs.png" alt="twbs" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" width="32" height="32">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <h6 class="mb-0">Another title here</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">Some placeholder content in a paragraph that goes a little longer so it wraps to a new line.</p>
            </div>
            <small class="opacity-50 text-nowrap">3d</small>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3 active" aria-current="true">
        <img src="https://github.com/twbs.png" alt="twbs" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" width="32" height="32">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <h6 class="mb-0">Third heading</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</p>
            </div>
            <small class="opacity-50 text-nowrap">1w</small>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3">
        <img src="https://github.com/twbs.png" alt="twbs" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" width="32" height="32">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <h6 class="mb-0">Some heading</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</p>
            </div>
            <small class="opacity-50 text-nowrap">1w</small>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3">
        <img src="https://github.com/twbs.png" alt="twbs" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" width="32" height="32">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <h6 class="mb-0">Some heading</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</p>
            </div>
            <small class="opacity-50 text-nowrap">1w</small>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3">
        <img src="https://github.com/twbs.png" alt="twbs" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" width="32" height="32">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <h6 class="mb-0">Some heading</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</p>
            </div>
            <small class="opacity-50 text-nowrap">1w</small>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex gap-3 py-3">
        <img src="https://github.com/twbs.png" alt="twbs" class="rounded-circle flex-shrink-0" width="32" height="32">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2 w-100 justify-content-between">
            <div>
                <h6 class="mb-0">Some heading</h6>
                <p class="mb-0 opacity-75">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</p>
            </div>
            <small class="opacity-50 text-nowrap">1w</small>
        </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```